What if I delay taking bath after nightfall (nocturnal emission)?
According to our constitution,to stay sacred taking bath after nightfall(nocturnal emission) is mandatory. Due to allergic issue if I take bath at day time instead of midnight or late night. Is there any wrong or what should I do?

Your question is unclear. If the nocturnal emission takes place during the night you can delay taking a bath till fajr but you need to perform it for offering fajr prayers. If the water is too cold at that time then you can warm it.
